# React Script exits immediate after starting development server using docker run command

Tags: reactjs, docker

I installed the module called create-react-app then executed this **create-react-app frontend** command for project generation. Its a custom image. After the project generated I made the custom docker YAML file for custom image generation. The image was generated successfully. But while running that image using this command **docker run b99c49b119be** it's exiting immediately after saying starting the development server. See below for the error.

I ran command for custom image generation **docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .**

**Error**

```
Successfully built b99c49b119be
[root@client frontend]# docker run b99c49b119be

> frontend@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For development purpose, just use `npm start` which uses react-scripts to run and watch  your application for changes.

To deploy your application using docker, you can use static files server like serve in docker. Use dockerfile below.

```
FROM node:8-alpine

RUN npm install serve -g

COPY build/ .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "."]
```

Before you build the image, run `npm run build` to produce a production ready distribution - which is a collection of all files in `build` folder of your project

For more details on how to deploy react app created with `create-react-app` [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the -it flag to run the container in interactive mode (keep STDIN open and allocate a pseudo-tty):

```
docker run -it CONTAINER_ID
```

This is caused due to recent update in the Create React App library and adding this flag should resolve your issue.